# config.py with 'if' statement on Flask

Tags: flask, celery

is there a chance im having some trouble using a if statement inside a config.py file in flask ? i have seen some examples of doing such a thing but maybe im doing something wrong because celery doesnt recognize the conf 'CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'

```
class Config(object):

    if 'VCAP_SERVICES' in os.environ:

        print('Vcap detectado', file=sys.stdout)

        REDIS_URL = os.environ.get('REDIS_BASE_URL').format(cert_type='required') 

        CELERY_BROKER_URL = os.environ.get('REDIS_BASE_URL').format(cert_type='CERT_REQUIRED') 

    else:

        REDIS_URL = 'redis://'

        CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'


    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = CELERY_BROKER_URL
```

----UPDATE----

The error celery is throwing me is this one, but rarely just some times i get this errors, others **AsyncResult** works fine:

```
AttributeError: 'DisabledBackend' object has no attribute '_get_task_meta_for'
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Updated the Post

Answer (score 0):

From my research i found that nobody does this and it is a bad practice, much more clean to have a config.py with a basic configuration for testing and then i create antother for my server.

```
app.config.from_object('yourapplication.default_settings')
app.config.from_envvar('YOURAPPLICATION_SETTINGS')
```

and adding this second line of code now i only have to set the new env variable in the server and i have 2 clean files with its configuration variables